# Can I decide whether to use the payload that is returned by dataweave lookup?

Tags: mule, lookup, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am using dataweave lookup to return additional information for a payload message.

Is there a way I can decide whether I can use the payload returned from the flow if the message status is not one I want?

I can't seem to get the syntax correct so far using when and otherwise conditions and cannot see much help online.

The lookup function is being called on the fly if the payload contains an error message and will remove the user record.  The lookup returns an object containing 2 fields and I only want to include the result if it status field is "rollback"

Dataweave code:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    (data: {
        userId: flowVars.userId,
        Message: "User created successfully"
    }) when (payload.user?) and 
            ((payload.status == "SUCCESS")),

    (Exception: {
        userId: flowVars.userId,
        Message: payload.exception.message,
        ("data":lookup("deleteuserfromgroup",payload.userId))
    })when (payload.exception?) and 
           (payload.exception.status != "-1")
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many conditional example in [DataWeave Reference Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation). Following is one of the simple examples:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var lookupValue = lookup("flowName", payload)
---
{
    //set default when null
    default: lookupValue default "defaultValue",
    //when or otherwise
    when: lookupValue when lookupValue.status == "expectedValue" otherwise "defaultValue",
    //display the element only when the expected value is returned
    (conditional: lookupValue) when lookupValue.status == "expectedValue"
}
```

You can combine or chain the expression as needed.

Comment: Hi.  The lookup will be called on the fly and have updated my question with the dataweave code showing where it will be called